# How to update or append an XML node during loop?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Here is my xml:

```
<rootNode>
    <sample>
        <DO type="TD" name="ABC" ref="1">
            <text>text</text>
        </DO>
        <DO type="CI" name="DEF" ref="2">
            <text></text>
        </DO>
        <DO type="PL" name="GHI" ref="3">
            <text>text</text>
        </DO>
        <DO type="AB" name="JKL" ref="4">
            <text>text</text>
        </DO>   
    </sample>
    <Docs>
        <Document>
            <type>TD</type>
            <name>ABC</name>
            <ref>1</ref>
            <text>sample text</text>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <type>CI</type>
            <name>DEF</name>
            <ref>2</ref>
            <text>sample text</text>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <type>PL</type>
            <name>GHI</name>
            <ref>3</ref>
            <text>sample text</text>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <type>AB</type>
            <name>JKL</name>
            <ref>4</ref>
            <text>sample text</text>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <type>CD</type>
            <name>JKL</name>
            <ref>5</ref>
            <text>sample text</text>
        </Document>
    </Docs>
</rootNode>
```

If any of the sample/DO 's type, name and ref matches with any of the Docs/Document type, name and ref. Update the sample/DO/text with Document/text. Otherwise (If any of the sample/Do 's type,name, ref is not matching with Docs/Document type, name, ref), the entire Document from Docs/Document should be appended.

Note: Order of the sample/DO should not change. I mean if any document is having any matches same should be updated. Otherwise new one should be appended.

Comment: are you using purely xpath or maybe another language with it

Comment: need to acheive it using xpath (1.0 or 2.0)

Comment: @bose: What do you mean by this: "Otherwise (If any of the sample/Do 's type,name, ref is not matching with Docs/Document type, name, ref), the entire Document from Docs/Document should be appended." *Which*  `Docs/Document ` should be appended? Please, explain.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT to copy and transform the document, you could make use of two **xsl:key**s to look up **Document** elements and **SO** elements. In this case you need a compound key

```
<xsl:key name="docs" match="Document" use="concat(type, '|', name, '|', ref)"/>
<xsl:key name="samples" match="DO" use="concat(@type, '|', @name, '|', @ref)"/>
```

You can firstly match **SO** elements that have a matching **Document** element like so

```
<xsl:template match="DO[key('docs', concat(@type, '|', @name, '|', @ref))]">
```

(If all **SO** elements were guaranteed to have a matching **Document element, this could be simplified to `<xsl:template match="DO" >`)

Within this template you could then simply add code to this template to copy the **text** element from the **Document** element in the key.

To match **Document** elements without a corresponding **SO** element, you could do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="/rootNode/Docs/Document[not(key('samples', concat(type, '|', name, '|', ref)))]"
   mode="Document"/>
```

And for the matching template, you could transform it to an **SO** element.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="docs" match="Document" use="concat(type, '|', name, '|', ref)"/>
   <xsl:key name="samples" match="DO" use="concat(@type, '|', @name, '|', @ref)"/>


   <xsl:template match="DO[key('docs', concat(@type, '|', @name, '|', @ref))]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('docs', concat(@type, '|', @name, '|', @ref))/text"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sample">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/rootNode/Docs/Document[not(key('samples', concat(type, '|', name, '|', ref)))]" mode="Document"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Document" mode="Document">
         <DO type="{type}" name="{name}" ref="{ref}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="text" />
         </DO>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Docs" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is output

```
<rootNode>
   <sample>
      <DO type="TD" name="ABC" ref="1">
         <text>sample text</text>
      </DO>
      <DO type="CI" name="DEF" ref="2">
         <text>sample text</text>
      </DO>
      <DO type="PL" name="GHI" ref="3">
         <text>sample text</text>
      </DO>
      <DO type="AB" name="JKL" ref="4">
         <text>sample text</text>
      </DO>
      <DO type="CD" name="JKL" ref="5">
         <text>sample text</text>
      </DO>
   </sample>
</rootNode>
```

Do note I excluded the **Docs** node from the output, but just delete the relevant line from the XSLT if you want to keep them.

Comment: Vow :-)
Thanks so much. This is exactly what i was looking out for.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you cant update the document just by using the pure xpath the idea of xpath is mostly used to select specific nodes from the document based on certain comparison. The only good way to achieve this you need to use another language where you can use xpath and also update element could be something like php Simplexml. Reading different sources many people recommend different suggestions but it mostly resolves with xquery here are couple of links.

http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/

http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10-use-cases/

http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/